# Property of Binomial Coefficient

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I have a "must be trivial" problem which I could not solve.

Prove the following relation of binomial coefficients, if true:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}{2n+1 \choose k}=2^{2n}-1$$

P.S. Though this is not homework, I appreciate any hints rather than explicit solutions.

I am looking for proofs from properties of binomial coefficients rather than other methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have that
$$\sum_{k=0}^{2n+1} \dbinom{2n+1}k = 2^{2n+1}$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \dbinom{2n+1}k + \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n+1} \dbinom{2n+1}k = 2^{2n+1}$$
Now note that
$$\dbinom{2n+1}k = \dbinom{2n+1}{2n+1-k}$$
Hence, we get that
$$2\sum_{k=0}^{n} \dbinom{2n+1}k = 2^{2n+1}$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \dbinom{2n+1}k = 2^{2n}$$
$$ \dbinom{2n+1}0 + \sum_{k=1}^{n} \dbinom{2n+1}k = 2^{2n} \implies \sum_{k=1}^{n} \dbinom{2n+1}k = 2^{2n} - 1$$

Answer (score 6):

Substitute $x=1$ into $(1+x)^{2n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{2n+1}\binom{2n+1}{k}x^k$ to obtain  $2^{2n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{2n+1}\binom{2n+1}{k}=2\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n+1}{k}$ since $\binom{2n+1}{k}=\binom{2n+1}{2n+1-k}$.

Answer (score 3):

Use this result (Binomial Theorem)
$$(a + b)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} a^k b^{n-k}.$$